# SSH Permission denied error in virtual box Guest

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox

I am running `Virtualbox 5.0.18` with `ubuntu desktop 14.04` distribution.

There are 4 VMs, 3 with `ubuntu server 14.04` , 1 running `ubuntu Desktop 14.04`.

All VMs have NAT and Host-only network configured.

- SSH to `ubuntu Desktop 14.04`, VM and host machine, is doing ok
- SSH to VMs running `ubuntu server 14.04` is giving me `permission denied error`.

Which logs should I look, to figure out the problem?
Ping is working, both way, for servers as well as desktop  and `telnet host 22` is ok for desktop only

Comment: Hi @Sawan, try to save your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in the VM that is denied and copy the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` from the boxes that is working, into the box. See the results

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [ubuntu.se], [unix.se], or [su].

Comment: @Kenster, I am sorry. I posted at askubuntu.com first but didn't get any response even after 2 days so I posted here hoping to get it resolved ASAP.

Comment: @Andy K, both have the same content. no luck.

Comment: Don't worry @Sawan. You are at the right place. Have you tried to do a `telnet host 22` to see if the port was opened?

Comment: Yeah port is opend, see below the o/p of telenet host 22<br>
Trying 192.168.59.1...<br>
Connected to 192.168.59.1.<br>
Escape character is '^]'.<br>
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6

Comment: This issue is only happening with ubuntu-server guest not with ubuntu-desktop guest. As people have pointed that to SSH from host to guest running ubuntu-server(both NAT and host-only configured) we need to do port mapping which is not needed in case of ubuntu-desktop

Comment: Have you tried that ? https://www.ulyaoth.net/resources/tutorial-ssh-into-a-virtualbox-linux-guest-from-your-host.35/

Comment: Did you try that too? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21302/ssh-connection-refused-how-to-troubleshoot

Comment: And this @Sawan http://www.unixlore.net/articles/troubleshooting-ssh-connections.html ?

Comment: @Andy K, Thank you so much for your help. Actually there was error in Host-only network configuration, after resolving that its working fine.

Comment: Cool @Sawan. Would you minding me put the answer here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in my comments.

You need to see if your `sshd` has started. if yes, you need to figure out the logs. One of the advice would be to start your sshd with some -d options to get more verbose debug output.

And see this [blog](https://www.ulyaoth.net/resources/tutorial-ssh-into-a-virtualbox-linux-guest-from-your-host.35/) if your vbox's config is the same.

Last but not least, [here is the step by step](http://www.computerworld.com/article/2494764/data-center/server-s-down--how-do-i-find-out-what-s-wrong-.html) troubleshooting for any linux appliances

All the best